# pandas multiindex dataframe conditional columns concatanation

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 2 multi index dataframes

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Country': [ 'US', 'IT', 'FR'],
                'Unit': [ 'USD', 'EUR', 'EUR'],
                  'Location': [ 'Hawai', 'Torino', 'Paris'],
                  '2000': [666, 888,777],
                    '2002': [44,55,66]
                   })
df2.set_index(['Country','Unit','Location'],inplace=True)

df3 = pd.DataFrame({'Country': [ 'US', 'IT', 'FR'],
                'Unit': [ 'USD', 'EUR', 'EUR'],
                  '2018': [666, 888,777]
                   })
df3.set_index(['Country','Unit'],inplace=True)  
                       2000  2002
Country Unit Location            
US      USD  Hawai      666    44
IT      EUR  Torino     888    55
FR      EUR  Paris      777    66
              2018
Country Unit      
US      USD    666
IT      EUR    888
FR      EUR    777
```

I would like to have a dataframe result with a thid column with values only for EUR, the other should stay blank as below

```
                      2000  2002 2018
Country Unit Location                 
US      USD  Hawai      666    44     
IT      EUR  Torino     888    55  888
FR      EUR  Paris      777    66  777
```

Tried concatenation but not sure it's the correct approach ?  Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

Use [`join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) with [`DataFrame.xs`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.xs.html) for select by second level of `MultiIndex`:

```
df = df2.join(df3.xs('EUR', level=1, drop_level=False))
print (df)
                       2000  2002   2018
Country Unit Location                   
US      USD  Hawai      666    44    NaN
IT      EUR  Torino     888    55  888.0
FR      EUR  Paris      777    66  777.0
```

Detail:

```
print (df3.xs('EUR', level=1, drop_level=False))
              2018
Country Unit      
IT      EUR    888
FR      EUR    777
```

Solution working in `pandas 0.22.0` - convert 3. level of MultiIndex to column for same number of levels in both `DataFrame`s by [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html), `join` and last [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) with `append=True` for avoid drop original index values:

```
df = (df2.reset_index(level=2)
         .join(df3.xs('EUR', level=1, drop_level=False))
         .set_index('Location', append=True))
print (df)
                       2000  2002   2018
Country Unit Location                   
US      USD  Hawai      666    44    NaN
IT      EUR  Torino     888    55  888.0
FR      EUR  Paris      777    66  777.0
```

Comment: Indeed, I've tried this but get an exception back  NotImplementedError: merging with more than one level overlap on a multi-index is not implemented

Comment: @Crovish - It working in pandas 0.24.1, can you upgrade?

Comment: I have to use pandas 0.22.0. Any idea how to make it work there ?

Comment: @Crovish - How working `df = df2.reset_index(level=2).join(df3.xs('EUR', level=1, drop_level=False)).set_index('Location', append=True)` ?

Comment: @Crovish - Super, can you also accept tis solution? thanks.